# How to inject vararg variable using hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, dagger-hilt

How to inject a mutable variable using hilt?

Please refer to the code below

```
open class BaseUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val baseRepository: BaseRepository
) {
}

// Possible
open class BaseViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val baseUseCase: BaseUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

}

// Impossible (How to make it possible)
open class BaseViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private vararg val baseUseCase: BaseUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

}
```

Comment: How's a `vararg` a `mutable` variable?

Comment: Author, could you please specify whether you're trying to inject multiple instances of `BaseUseCase` or if you want to make the `baseUseCase` field mutable from inside `BaseViewModel`?
`vararg` refers to variable number of arguments ([docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs)), `var` is a readable and writeable variable ([docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters)).